# JOINing three tables with Distinct Query - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables as below

Subjects

```
SubID(pk)  IntrvlID   SubjectName

sub1        1         English
sub2        1         English
sub3        3         Chinese
sub4        4         Spanish
```

StudentVsSubject

```
StudentID   SubID   
AAAA        sub1      
AAAA        sub2      
AAAA        sub3      
BBBB        sub3       
AAAA        sub4
```

SubmissionDetails

```
SubmissionID  StudentID    SubID     IntrvlID   SubmittedAt
100            AAAA        sub1       1          19/06/2020
101            AAAA        sub3       3          17/06/2020
```

And the resulted Output should be (of student AAAA)

```
  IntrvlID     StudentID    SubID       SubmittedAt
     1           AAAA        sub1          19/06/2020  
     3           AAAA        sub3          17/06/2020
     4           AAAA        NULL           NULL
```

If the SubmissionDetails is empty,
The result should be (of student AAAA)

```
   IntrvlID     StudentID    SubID       SubmittedAt
     1           AAAA        NULL          NULL  
     3           AAAA        NULL          NULL
     4           AAAA        NULL          NULL
```

Means,First I have to get DISTINCT 'IntrvlID' assigned to student 'AAA' and have to join these three tables.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet, and, if so, can you include your attempt in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `left join` like following

```
select
    distinct IntrvlID,
    ss.StudentID,
    s.SubId,
    SubmittedAt
from Subject s
left join StudentVsSubject ss
on s.SubId = ss.SubId
left join SubmissionDetails sd
on ss.StudentID = sd.StudentID
```

Comment: This will return an extra row with intrvalID 1 additional to original output

Comment: @user2431727 try now.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select distinct sd.IntrvlID, s.StudentID, sd.SubID, sd.SubmittedAt from 
SubmissionDetails sd
left outer join StudentVsSubject ss
on (sd.StudentID=ss.StudentID)
left outer join Subjects s
on (s.IntrvlID = sd.IntrvlID);
```

Comment: This will not return itevalID with NULL values